# how to add custom font files to template

Tags: theming, 8

I like to add my custom font to my custom theming. All the font-files are in the file FONTS. And I also have a fonts.css file.
Where do I have to declare all this stuff?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use libraries. Take a look here for a detailed explination: https://www.kinetasystems.com/blog/adding-google-fonts-to-a-drupal-8-theme

Comment: This is not exactly what I am looking for, because I have my own font-files and no extern like from google.

Comment: it is the same for external and internal css files: https://www.drupal.org/theme-guide/8/assets

Comment: This is a good example of why just linking to an answer isn't sufficient and answers should provide more detail. The link is down.

Answer (score 0):

Since the accepted answer is a link to a dead site I have copy and pasted the article here from the waybackmachine

all credits to 'Nik' who submitted the article on 16 December 2015 - 3:04pm

> This took a bit more work to figure out than in Drupal 7! Bear in
> mind, this example is for installing a theme-wide (every page) font.
> There's references at the bottom where you might find further
> information on other methods.
>
> Here's the old way of inserting Google Fonts (for every page using
> this theme):
>
> ```
> function MYTHEME_preprocess_html(&$variables) {
>   // this function is deprecated in D8 because, caching, I think
>   drupal_add_css('//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oxygen:300', array('group' => CSS_THEME));
> }
> ```
>
> In Drupal 8, however, we have to use the libraries method, which is "a
> bit" more involved. Firstly, we need to add a library to our
> theme.info.yml (see last two lines). Here, I've made a subtheme of
> Bartik to implement the feature against. Side note: the base theme
> name is not capitalised. This didn't work when I tried it, but is ok
> all lower case. Seems a bizarre thing, when the original theme is
> declared like `name: Bartik` but there you go.
>
> ```
> name: Blah
> description: It's a theme
> type: theme
> base theme: bartik
> core: 8.x
> libraries:
>   - themeName/fonts
> ```
>
> Then we need to create the library file. For whatever reason, the
> library is defined as `themeName/libraryName` in the `.info.yml`. The
> library file is called `themeName.libraries.yml`. The library file opens
> with a declaration of `libraryName`:
>
> ```
> fonts:
>   license:
>     name: SIL Open Font License, 1.1
>     url: http://scripts.sil.org/cms/scripts/page.php?site_id=nrsi&id=OFL
>   css:
>     theme:
>       //fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oxygen:300: { type: external }
>       css/myStyles.css: {}
> ```
>
> This YML file actually works fine without the license section, but it
> would be a bit poor to not even attempt to honour it... NB The font
> url has had the **http:** removed so that it is agnostic to
> secure-or-not connections at runtime.
>
> If all that has worked, you should be able to view source on your site
> and see a comforting line of code like  All that remains is to implement the font in your CSS by inserting
> a rule in the myStyles.css file in the css folder, like:
>
> ```
> font-family: 'Oxygen', sans-serif;
> ```
>
> **References**
>
> [Adding stylesheets (CSS) and JavaScript (JS) to a Drupal 8 theme](https://www.drupal.org/theme-guide/8/assets)
>
> [Defining a theme with an .info.yml file](https://www.drupal.org/node/2349827)
>
> [Creating a Drupal 8 sub-theme](https://www.drupal.org/node/2165673)